# Describe a simplicial complex by its subcomplexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, combinatorial-geometry, simplicial-complex

Let $K$ be a pure simplicial complex of dimension $d$. I would like to ask, if there is a way to describe a simplicial complex by means of certain subcomplexes rather than by simplices. Suppose I understand that $K$ is constructed from two subcomplexes $A$ and $B$ of dimension $d$ that share a common subcomplex $C$ in its boundary, say of dimension $d'<d$.

For example let $A$ be the cone over a (stellar) subdivided edge $C$, that is $A=C\ast a$, and $B$ be another cone over $C$, that is, $B=C\ast b$, so that $A$ and $B$ coincide in $C$.

I feel that this information should suffice to fully describe $K$ up to simplicial isomorphism.

My question is, how can I formalize this information/construction within the context of the usual definition of a simplicial complex? To give the full set of simplices, which one has to do be definition, seems superfluous here.

Comment: Are you asking about pushouts of simplicial complexes?

Comment: If I topologize my spaces that's exactly what I would like to have. However, I would like to stay in the category of simplicial complexes. How is the pushout defined there? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly as you'd expect: given $A$, $B$, and $C$ as in your post, we get a new simplicial complex with vertex set given by the union of the vertex sets of $A$ and $B$ over $C$, and a something is a simplex of the pushout if it is a simplex of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: That was most helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for the pushouts of simplicial complexes.  Here is a recipe to compute them in the special case of working with subcomplexes.

Recall that a simplicial complex $X$ is the data of a set $V(X)$ of vertices together with a downward-closed family $S(X)$ of subsets of $V(X)$.  Given a span $$A \hookleftarrow C \hookrightarrow B$$ of inclusions of simplicial complexes, the pushout $A \cup_C B$ has vertices $$V(A \cup_C B) = V(A) \cup_{V(C)} V(B)$$ and simplices $$S(A \cup_C B) = S(A) \cup S(B).$$

However, while the pushout still exists if $C$ is not a subcomplex of $A$ and $B$, its description is more complicated.  Moreover, it is not true that geometric realization preserves these pushouts in general, so pushouts in simplicial complexes and the corresponding pushouts in topological spaces could look different.

Comment: Thanks again for the full answer. Do you have a simple example for your last caveat about geometric realizations?

Comment: Consider the pushout of $* \leftarrow \{0,1\} \rightarrow [0,1]$.